# Blocking users from downloading files on mobile devices

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, mobile, download

I'm currently researching ways to restrict users from being able to download files on mobile devices, that are not managed by my company. I'm aware that Microsoft offers an easy solution for this, but unfortunately this requires an upgrade of our license to Enterprise Mobility + Security.
Is there another way to achieve restricting downloads to mobile devices? I've looked into working with the Sharepoint online managment shell but without any success.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Conditional Access Policies in Azure AD which will require licensing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there no way to do this with the sharepoint shell? The documentation provided by Microsoft is quite vague.